# phase unwrap issue (the unwrapping of the phases is not correcly)?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have an issue regard to the unwrapping of phases over time.

I have a radar which monitors a slow periodic moving object. From the received signal, i want to see the phase of the object over time. The phase-over-time signal is extracted from FFTs (at the same FFT bin for all the FFTs). Here is the result i got:
[image]

Because the phases are wrapped, so I need to do an unwrapping for the phases. I use the Matlab command "*unwrap*" to to this. So I got: 
[image]

The issue is marked at the red circle. Here I expect the signal at this time-instant to be unwrapped. However it wasn't, and the reason is:

```
- From time sample NO. 42 -> 44, the phases take two time samples to being
wrapped, instead of only one (i.e between two consecutive time samples).
Because of this the phase-over-time signal are not unwrapped correctly.
```

I also tried to used another phase-unwrapping method (Adaptive numerical integration), however the result is the same as using "*unwrap*" command from Matlab.

Here is the phase-over-time signal I expected to see (I did the unwrapping manually):
[image]

What is the problem mentioned above (Is it a well-known problem or has any name for it)? And of course what is the solution for this?

I would really appreciate any help from you! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 5):

Matlab's `unwrap` function tries to avoid any jumps between consecutive values larger than `tol`. By default, `tol` is pi. Your jumps from -1.644 to -0.7 to 1.55 are not larger than pi, so `unwrap` doesn't find it necessary to adjust your data. Note, even if the -0.7 wasn't in there, `unwrap` still wouldn't adjust your data as the jump would still be less than pi.

The tolerance is an optional parameter in `unwrap`, you can set:

```
unwrap(x,tol)
```

I would suggest setting your tolerance to pi/2 or 3*pi/4, depending on your data.

The `unwrap` documentation probably has more information

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html?refresh=true

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RPM
If -0.7 was not there, then the jump is (1.55 - -1.644 = 3.194 > pi), so it would be counted as a jump. I think the "unwrap" command is fine. I also tried to unwrap the phases using Adaptive Numerical Integration method, however the result is the same. I think it's somehow a problem of the signal itself. 
And btw I think "unwrap" command does not work for jump less than pi even if the "tol" value is set e.g pi/2.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your input signal is between `-pi` and `pi` an your desired output between `0` and `2pi`, so why dont'you simply add `2pi` to the negative values ? Here is a try:

```
I = s<0;
s(I) = s(I) + 2*pi;
```

That should provide the desired output, in a more simpler way.

Best,

Comment: Thanks @Ratbert
Actually I don't really care about the absolute value of the signal, I concern more about its correct shape, cause I want to estimate is frequency.

Comment: I understand, my point here is not to put the signal in a given range but to transform the signal to the desired output. Give it a try and you'll see that it answers your problem without the use of `unwrap`.

Comment: Thanks very much @Ratbert.  
I did try and the result looks better. However now it has some problems with parts of signal which are around the zero-level. These parts of signal have some unexpected jumps which is not wanted (not the above signal, it's a very simple one for illustrating my problem. The actually signal is more noisy).
I'm trying to find the solution for these incorrectly jumps!