# How to lowpass filter an angle value

Tags: java, math, geometry, filtering, computational-geometry

I'm receiving angle updates from a sensor in radians and I want to pass them through a low pass filtering function to smooth them slightly because of noise.

My low pass filter function looks like this

```
protected void lowPass(float alpha, double[] input, double[] output) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output[i] = alpha * output[i] + (1 - alpha) * input[i];
    }
}
```

and it works great for the most parts.

The problem is that sometimes the angles "go full circle", e.g. from 2π to 0, 0 to -2π, etc. Of course this results in "incorrect" output, since the filter function treats 2π and 0 as simply 6.28 and 0.0.

How would I implement a filter function that can handle these kinds of angles correctly?

Answer (score 3):

There is interesting approach used for [angle averaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities).

Get cosine and sine of angle alpha (as components of vector with this angle) and use them for separate filtering, then get angle for result vector

```
 cosa = alpha * cos(output) + (1 - alpha) * cos(input);
 sina = alpha * sin(output) + (1 - alpha) * sin(input);
 output = atan2(sina, cosa)
```

Comment: Interesting indeed. There is a little bias for α <> 1/2 because this constructs the point at the fraction α of the chord, which is not exactly at the fraction α of the arc. But this is a second order effect.

Answer (score 2):

For exponential smoothing like that, the easiest approach is to add or subtract 2*pi from each input to make it as close as possible to the previous smoothed value. Or, equivalently, add or subtract 2*pi from the previous output before smoothing to the input. In either case, your outputs can temporarily pass outside the [0,2*pi) range, so make sure to wrap back around into that range if you need it.

Incidentally, your code has a bug, in that it reads from the wrong output index and doesn't work properly with the first time value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform phase unwrapping, i.e. recover the 2π jumps that occur periodically. For this you can detect anomalies such as a value close to 2π immediately followed by a value close to 0, and conversely, and compensate.

Note that if the values change in large increments (say larger than π), the jumps are unrecoverable.

See [phase unwrap issue (the unwrapping of the phases is not correcly)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32442396/1196549).